# Gmail task integration with Evolution

Tags: 11.04, sync, evolution, gmail, task-management

Is it possible to integrate Gmail tasks with Evolution 2.32.2 running on Ubuntu 11.04?

I've had my calendar and contacts integrated for quite some time now but have been unsuccessful in getting tasks integrated. From what I've read it may not even be possible, but I'm unsure whether it's a limitation of Gmail or Evolution, or whether it's supposed to be fixed in the near term.

Thanks

Comment: Possible with third party tool syncevolution & syncml web service like memotoo.See my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122808/sync-google-calendar-tasks-with-evolution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tasks are currently not supported in Evolution due to missing support for Google Tasks in underlying library (libgdata).

There's a bug entry in Gnome's Bugzilla for that: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652132

Comment: Perfect - thanks. I shall check periodically on this. Interesting that it was reported only 3 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for same, and as I run 11.04 I can't use something like [google-task-indicator](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/google-tasks-indicator-quick-access-to.html) even if I wanted.

As Evolution is nicely integrated with date/time indicator, I thought to take advantage of that.

I first tried [RTM](http://www.rememberthemilk.com) which I thought to interface with [Tasque](http://live.gnome.org/Tasque) but found that RTM integration in Tasque is buggy. Then I left RTM interface for later and tried to export RTM events to my Google calendar account which I integrate in Evolution. Either importing RTM event ical calendar in Google calendar or directly in Evolution as new calendar, resulted in calendar without events, although I created couple of test tasks in RTM Inbox and give 1 hour time-out for both scenarios.
Here, another possibility which does not seem too useful to me, would be RSS export from RTM and then use some RSS indicator to track this tasks, but already discouraged by previous writing I looked for other approach.

So, I made new calendar in Google calendar, called Tasks, and added it to my Evolution calendars. This may not be solution for all, but for me it's enough. I can add "tasks" thought Evolution "Add event..." action from date/time indicator, but for quicker way I made "shortcut" script called "add-task" wrapped around [googlecl](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) and put it in `~/.local/bin/`:

```
google calendar add --cal Tasks "$@"
```

and then from terminal I can quickly add task like:

```
$ add-task "Finish that paper for 3 days"
```

which will show in date/time indicator (pale yellow colored), for next 3 days:

[image]

This is one working possibility, and it seems easy to make yet other different approaches, with or without downloading too much software

Hope someone finds it useful ^_^