# How can I view google tasks in Evolution?

Tags: evolution, google-calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sync Google Calendar Tasks with Evolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122808/sync-google-calendar-tasks-with-evolution)

I'm using ubuntu 12, and i have my google account added as an "online account" so it shows up in evolution. However there doesn't seem to be support for gmail tasks yet..

Is there any program to easily view my google tasks? The only way I can seem to view the task list from my computer is through the web browser which is not very convenient.